# Testing a thread Worker with an anonymous function

Tags: rust

I am adding tests to the ['hello' web server](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-02-multithreaded.html) from the rust book.
My issue/error is around how to test whether a `Worker` has processed a `Job`.

My idea is to pass an anonymous function which updates a `bool` from *false* to *true*.
I think ownership is an issue here. I tried wrapping `f` in a `Box`, thinking it would prevent passing `bool` as a value as opposed to a reference. Using `Box` I struggled to mutate the value of `state_updated` when it was wrapped in this way.
I also tried writing a basic `struct` to wrap and update the `bool`. I have since reverted back to a `mut bool`.

**First question**: What changes do I need to make to get the test to pass?

**Second question**: Is there a better way for me to test this?

---

Below is a minimal version which reproduces my issue.
The full code is available at the bottom of [this page in the rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-03-graceful-shutdown-and-cleanup.html).

My current test creates a `Worker`, sends a `Job` to the worker, and asserts on an expected change
that could only have occurred if the Worker has processed the Job.
I intend to iterate on this test to add proper thread cleanup in the future.

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;

use hello_server_help::Worker;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

#[test]
fn test_worker_processes_job() {
    let (sender, r) = mpsc::channel();
    let receiver = Arc::new(Mutex::new(r));

    let _ = Worker::new(0, receiver);

    let mut state_updated = false;
    let f = move || state_updated = true;

    sender.send(Box::new(f)).unwrap();

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)); // primitive wait, for now

    assert_eq!(state_updated, true);
}
```

It's my understanding that `f` is taking ownership of `state_updated`. In the assert line, however,
at the end, there is no error along the lines of "referenced after move".

Running the tests gives me the output:

```
running 1 test
test test_worker_processes_job ... FAILED

failures:

---- test_worker_processes_job stdout ----
thread 'test_worker_processes_job' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `false`,
 right: `true`', tests/worker_tests.rs:19:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

The [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) implementation:

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;

pub type Job = Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>;

pub struct Worker {
    id: usize,
    handle: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl Worker {
    pub fn new(id: usize, receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Job>>>) -> Worker {
        let thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let job = receiver
                .lock()
                .expect("Error obtaining lock.")
                .recv()
                .unwrap();

            job();
        });

        Worker {
            id,
            handle: Some(thread),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state_updated` is a boolean so it implements `Copy`, which is why you can move it into your closure and keep using it afterwards, and why you can't see the changes: the one that is modified by the closure is the copy and not the original.

If you want to update a boolean in the thread and have it visible in the caller, you will need to make sure that you send a reference and you will need to have some synchronization mechanism. Two solutions:

- Use an `Arc<Mutex<bool>>`:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;

let state_updated = Arc::new (Mutex::new (false));
let state_ref = state_updated.clone()
let f = move || *state_ref.lock().unwrap() = true;
…
assert_eq!(*state_updated.lock().unwrap(), true);
```

- Or use an [`AtomicBool`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html):

```
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool;
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering;

let state_updated = AtomicBool::new (false);
let state_ref = &state_updated;
let f = move || state_ref.store (true, Ordering::Release);
…
assert_eq!(state_updated.load (Ordering::Acquire), true);
```

The compiler will complain that "`state_ref` *does not live long enough*", but you can get around that by using a [scoped thread](https://docs.rs/scoped-thread/0.1.1/scoped_thread/) (or from [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/fn.scope.html) or [crossbeam](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.1/crossbeam/fn.scope.html)), or with a bit of unsafe: `let state_ref: &'static AtomicBool = unsafe { transmute (&state_updated) };` (just make sure you join the child thread before `state_updated` goes out of scope).

It might however be better to use a channel for the return value:

```
use use std::sync::mpsc;

let (rsend, rrecv) = mpsc::channel();
let f = move || rsend.send(());
…
assert_eq!(rrecv.recv_timeout (Duration::from_secs (1)), Ok(()));
```

that way you only wait until the result is available (the duration is just a timeout if the thread takes too long to compute the result).

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jmb. Even though I am already using `Arc` and `Mutex` in the `src/` code I like the idea of `AtomicBool`. The `Arc<Mutex<bool>>` solution works and the test is passing!

However I get the error: _"`state_updated` does not live long enough borrowed value does not live long enough"_ on the line `let state_ref = &state_updated;` which I can't figure out.

Comment: Overall your suggestion to use `mpsc::channel` I agree is the best approach to avoid having to sleep for a fixed time!